# handlebars and if else

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a view of the handlebars, I want to be in it was checking whether a variable IF js == 'foo'

```
<div class="title"><label for="inputSearch">{{#if variable == 'foo'}} AAA {{else}} BB {{/if}}</label></div>
  <ul class="top-buttons">
    <li class="back"><a href="#" id="priev_es">Wstecz</a></li>
    <li class="more"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But I have this error in the console:

```
handlebars.js:286Error: Parse error on line 2:
{{#if variable == 'foo'}} AAA {{else
----------------^
Expecting 'DATA', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', got 'EQUALS'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars has no in-built syntax for performing equality checks.

You have to put that sort of logic in your JavaScript, not your template.

You can [express it as a helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) that you can call from your template though.

Comment: i have:

    Handlebars.registerHelper('language', function() {
    if (language == pl)
    {
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
    });

and TPL


    {{#if language}} EN {{else} PL {{/if}}

But on this error.
Something I did wrong?.

Comment: You got an error, so yes, you did something wrong. The error should tell you what. I can't see the error report you got.

Comment: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'depth0.language')

Comment: The error is right. You are defining a callback in registerHelper and this is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

you have got to send in arguments to the annonymous function that you have bound to the name 'language' and then compare those 2 args and return true or false. According to the returned value use if else in handlebars